# How to prove the union of conditional probabilities is a value?

Tags: probability-theory

$B_1, B_2, ..., B_n$ are mutually disjoint, and $B=\bigcup_{j=1}^nB_j$. Suppose $P(B_j)>0$ and $P(A|B_j)=p$ for $j=1,...,n$. Show that $P(A|B)=p$.

I know that $P(A|B_j)=\frac{P(A\cap B_j)}{P(B_j)}=p$. It's clear to me that if I can just take the summation of the top and bottom, I would get what I need for $P(A|B)$, but I can't figure out how to make it so it is still equal to p.

Answer (score 1):

Proceed by definition:
\begin{gather}
 & P(A | B) = \frac{P( A \cap B) }{P(B)} = \frac{\sum_{j} P(A \cap B_j)}{P(B)} \\
& = \sum_j \frac{P(A \cap B_j)}{P(B)} = \sum_j \frac{\frac{P(A \cap B_j)}{P(B_j)}}{\frac{P(B)}{P(B_j)}} \\ 
&= \sum_j \frac{p}{\frac{P(B)}{P(B_j)}} = p\sum_j \frac{ P(B_j)}{P(B)}  \\
& = p \frac{\sum_j P(B_j)}{P(B)}= p
\end{gather}